# Rearranging series' to converge to a certain point.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

> Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ a convergent but not absolutely convergent series.
>
> 1.1:   For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let 
>   $b_n:=max(a_n,0)$,  $c_n=-min(a_n,0)$
>
> Show that: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n=\infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n=\infty$.
>
> 1.2: Conclude, that for every $S\in \mathbb{R}$ there is a rearrangement $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$, so that the series which was rearranged by $\sigma$ converges to $S$, meaning
>
> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{\sigma (n)}=S$.

I'm sorry to repost this, but the original seemed to go nowhere and I have too low of a reputation to comment and I didn't want to use the answer option since I didn't have an answer. Anyway, here is the original one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333523/rearrangement-of-series-not-absolutely-convergent .

1.1:) Since the series is not absolutely convergent I can see how limit of the sequences with $b_n$ and $c_n$ are infinite since $b_n$ and $c_n$ can't be $0$ because that would consequently mean that it's absolutely convergent. 
But I don't know how to write and prove this idea mathematically.

1.2:) Like the original author I'm lost here, because I never dealt with rearranging series'. Is there a certain approach to those kind of things?

Comment: possible duplicate of [absolutely convergent series and conditionally convergent series rearrangement](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357224/absolutely-convergent-series-and-conditionally-convergent-series-rearrangement)

Comment: There are complete proofs online, including one on Wikipedia:  [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)

Comment: Oh, okay, now I get how 1.2. is solved. But I still don't know how to write down 1.1.